# How to connect VScode "Remote-SSH" using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Trying to develop in VSCode with [Remote Connection](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) and run/debug/... in a pod on kubernetes cluster.

How to connect VScode using kubectl?

Trying port forwarding

```
kubectl -n dev port-forward my-pod-name 22:22
```

It connects, works but getting errors:

```
E0604 10:58:15.025638   11216 portforward.go:385] error copying from local connection 
to remote stream: read tcp4 127.0.0.1:22->127.0.0.1:54495: wsarecv: An existing 
connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Answer (score 0):

Port 22 is a dedicated port which is reserved in your system that is why the connection cannot be established. Use the following snippet:

```
kubectl -n dev port-forward my-pod-name 8022:22
```

Comment: I did connect via 8022 and have the same error popping up when using the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the pod there is no running ssh-server?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The [kubernetes extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools) to VS code supports attaching remotely to pods.  When you use this extension, you don't need the remote SSH extension, or to configure SSH at all.

For an example of how to attach with this extension, see this documentation: [Attach to a running container using Visual Studio Code Remote Development — Attach to a container in a Kubernetes cluster](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/attach-container#_attach-to-a-container-in-a-kubernetes-cluster)